# Error: Call to a member function getFechaInicio() on null

Tags: php

Estoy teniendo problemas con este error y no puedo darme cuenta por qué es.

El error se da así:

Tengo por un lado un `form` el cual manda varios datos por `POST`, entre ellos una fecha. La información la recibo en otro archivo PHP donde proceso otros datos pero la fecha no la modifico. Luego creo el objeto `articulo`, el cual entre otras cosas tiene la fecha, y llamo a la función `altaArticulo`, la cual hace un INSERT.

Dentro de la función uso las funciones `get` para obtener los datos del objeto.  Todos los datos llegan bien menos la fecha la cual es `null`.

Éste es mi código:

```
$fecha_inicio = strip_tags($_POST['fecha_inicio']); //dd-mm-yy     
$fecha_inicio = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_inicio));
// Usando die(var_dump($fech_inicio) acá la variable tiene la fecha guardada correctamente

//Creo el objeto publicacion    
$p = new art_pub('',$id_articulo_ingresado,$id_usu,$fecha_inicio,$fecha_fin,$tipo_publicacion);

$q = $p->altaPublicacion($conex);
```

Función de alta en el archivo de la clase:

```
public function altaPublicacion($conex){
    $id_art=$this->getIdArt();
    $id_usu=$this->getIdUsu();
    $fecha_inicio->getFechaInicio();// En esta linea da el error
    $fecha_fin->getFechaFin();
    $tipo->getTipoVenta();


    $sql = "INSERT INTO `publica` (`fecha_in`,`fecha_fin`,`tipo`,`id_u`,`id_a`)
    VALUES (:fecha_inicio, :fecha_fin, :tipo, :id_usu, :id_art)";

    $result = $conex->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute(array(':fecha_inicio'=>$fecha_inicio, ':fecha_fin'=>$fecha_fin,':tipo'=>$tipo
    , ':id_usu'=>$id_usu, ':id_art'=>$id_art));

    // Guardo el id de la publicacion luego de insertar para redirigir a la publicacion finalizada
    $id_publicacion = $conex->lastInsertedId();

    return ($id_publicacion);
}
```

No me doy cuenta porque no recibe los datos. ¿Por qué puede ser y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: haz un var_dump de $fecha_inicio no existe ese objeto, creo  que con solo $fecha_inicio tienes

Comment: Pero una cosa, ¿`$fecha_inicio` está declarada como `private` en la cabecera de la clase? Si es así, debería ser: `$this->fecha_inicio =getFechaInicio();...`  y... si es así, ese método debería llamarse `set...` no `get...`   Y sólo por curiosidad, ¿a qué se debe el uso de `strip_tags`con el _$POST que tomas para la fecha-inicio?

Comment: @A.Cedano $fecha_inicio esta decalrada como private como tu dices. Y los otros metodos get funcionan bien. El uso de strip tags es para remover cualquier etiqueta php o html o bits null que de un input, por precaución lo utilizo en todos los imputs.

Comment: @JackNavaRow el var dum devuelve la fecha cuando lo hago en el archivo donde recibo el post, si lo hago en la clase articulo donde hago el  insert es null. Pero no deberia ser null

Comment: Si es como dices, y `getFechaInicio()` es un método de la misma clase, la forma en que funcione es esta: `$this->fecha_inicio = $this->getFechaInicio();` y si `getFechaInicio()`es un método estático, entonces sería: `$this->fecha_inicio =self::getFechaInicio();`. Si es así, para respetar las normas de la POO, ese método debería ser un setter, no un getter...

Comment: @A.Cedano Tenías razon faltataba =$this. No había interpretado bien tu respuesta. Muchas gracias, ahora anduvo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si `getFechaInicio()` es un método de la clase y  `$fecha_inicio` está declarada como `private` en la misma clase. Para acceder a ellos debes usar la palabra reservada `$this`.

Por ejemplo:

```
$this->fecha_inicio = $this->getFechaInicio();
```

Pero, si el método `getFechaInicio()` está declarado como `static` (estático), entonces para llamarlo tendrías que poner:

```
$this->fecha_inicio = self::getFechaInicio();
```

**Nota**:

Si es así, para respetar las normas de la POO, ese método debería ser un *setter*, no un *getter*..., llamándose algo así como `setFechaInicio()`. Es decir, en una clase las variables declaradas como `private` no pueden ser modificadas desde fuera de ella, eso se llama *encapsulación*.

Si tu método `getFechaInicio()` fuese público, se podría modificar **desde fuera de la clase** el valor de un miembro privado de la misma, por lo tanto, esa clase no cumpliría un principio esencial de la POO. Tendrías que tener entonces un método setter, para **modificar** su valor **desde dentro** y un método getter para **obtener** ese valor **desde fuera**. Algo así más o menos:

```
//getter: no puede modificar el valor
public function getFechaInicio() 
{
     return $this->fecha-inicio;
}


//setter: sí puede modificar el valor, pero desde dentro xq es private
private function setFechaInicio($valor) 
{
   $this->fecha_inicio = $valor;     
}
```

Por *convención de nombres*, ese tipo de métodos empiezan siempre por las palabras inglesas `get...` `set...`, seguidas de lo que getean o setean. Puedes llamarles como quieras, pero en programación es importante respetar la *convención de nombres*.